# How to set path to newly built GCC

Tags: gcc, paths

I just built and installed gcc6.3.0 for MATLAB, but I can't set the path to it. I tried

```
export PATH=/home/mo/GCC-6.3.0:$PATH
```

but this still gives the path to default gcc9.3.0. Ubuntu20.04.

Comment: Where exactly did you place the `export` command, and how did you invoke MATLAB after? Remember the export will only apply if you invoke MATLAB from the shell in which you exported the modified PATH

Comment: I wasn't checking in MATLAB, just exported in terminal and checked with `which gcc` therein. @steeldriver

Comment: So does the `gcc` binary executable exist directly in `/home/mo/GCC-6.3.0` or is it in a subdirectory like `bin`? Can you run `/home/mo/GCC-6.3.0/gcc -v` for example?

Comment: @steeldriver `/home/mo/GCC-6.3.0/bin/gcc --version` this works!

Comment: so now export with `bin` works. Ah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way for me was to export gcc's path in terminal as:

```
export PATH=/home/mo/GCC-6.3.0/bin:$PATH
```

and then open MATLAB from this terminal window as:

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2019a/bin
./matlab
```

check gcc path in MATLAB:

```
!which gcc
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to update the gcc configuration to make that your default compiler.

Add the compiler to the list of available compilers.

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /path/to/installation/bin/gcc-6.3 6
```

Activate the compiler. This will prompt you to select a compiler.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

Verify whether the changes have taken effect with `gcc --version`

For security reasons, it is not recommended to add directories especially to the beginning of the path, as explained in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059/417390).

Comment: thanks, before I try this, is there a way to undo this action too? I only need this gcc version for one program after which i would like to go back to the default

Comment: You can undo it by running "sudo update-alternatives --config gcc" again, and reselect your old compiler